# SQL: Update one field from different table

Tags: sql, sql-update

Let's say I have those two tables:

```
table1

ID        value1    value2
1         NULL      NULL
2         NULL      NULL
3         NULL      NULL

table2

ID        value3    value4
5         100       400
6         200       500
7         300       600
```

I need a SQL-statement to get `value3` and `value4` of `table2` `ID 7` into `value1` and `value2` of `table1` `ID 1`.
How do I go about that?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is to update two fields in a single row, you can do it with subqueries, like this:

```
update table1
set
    value1 = (select value3 from table2 where id=7)
,   value2 = (select value4 from table2 where id=7)
where id=1
```

For updating more fields in related rows of two tables [use an `UPDATE` with `JOIN` syntax appropriate from your RDBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1293330/335858).

Comment: Actually I need to update about 30 fields in one row. Thanks for the link.